# SQL Query to display all rows whose column doesnot start with given string

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching

I'm using Postgres SQL where I need to find cust_contact which does not start with string character J or M while the same query can be performed in Microsoft Excel using the code below:

```
       SELECT cust_contact
       FROM Customers
       WHERE cust_contact LIKE '[^JM]%'
       ORDER BY cust_contact;
```

how can we achieve the same task using PostgreSQl

Answer (score 2):

You may do a regex like here:

```sql
SELECT cust_contact
FROM Customers
WHERE cust_contact !~ '^[JM]'
ORDER BY cust_contact;
```

This would return all records for which the customer contact name does *not* start with `J` or `M`.

Comment: You probably want `!~*` to make it case insensitive

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah...I thought of doing that, but assumed that since the column contained only names, every name could therefore be assumed to start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command-

```
   SELECT cust_contact
   FROM Customers
   WHERE cust_contact NOT LIKE "J%" OR cust_contact NOT LIKE "M%"
   ORDER BY cust_contact;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
SELECT cust_contact
   FROM Customers
   WHERE cust_contact NOT LIKE "J%" AND cust_contact NOT LIKE "M%"
   ORDER BY cust_contact;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative WHERE clause:

```
...
...
WHERE cust_contact NOT LIKE ALL ("J%","M%")
...
...
```